# Ckeditor 4. (4.17.1) sometimes paste command is done twice

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I just upgrade from ckeditor 4.5.6 to 4.17.1.
Sometimes the paste (from Ctrl+v) is done twice. If I set ckeditor.on("paste") I receive two calls.
Is this normal? How can I prevent it? Could it be affected by any plugins?
With 4.5.6 it didn't happen, with the same code.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a call to: `ckeditor.fire("contentDom")`.
It affected to this issue (double paste) and it makes the source plugin to throw a message when going from source to wysiwyg.
Sorry for the post. I was my fault...